# Is it possible to use Python, AJAX & CGI together

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

**I want to have a web page where you click a button, by using AJAX I get a string from a python script, then display that string in a paragraph HTML element.**

**I know I can do this by using Python, WSGI & AJAX (theoretically I can do it this way) but its waaaay too difficult. I am experienced with CGI & python.**

**So can I do the above using CGI?**

If I can how do the python script work, exactly the same as when serving a page using CGI?

This doesn't work:

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import os


print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

input_data   = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "hello"
```

When I click my button in my page, nothing happens & my CGI server (which works fine for cgi page requests) gives me a http 501 error.

My html & javascript:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function onTest( dest, params )
            {
                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById( "bb" ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("POST",dest,true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send( params ); 
            }


        -->
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="bb"> abcdef </p>
        <a href="javascript:onTest('aaa.py', '')">Click it</a>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use a proper python webframework - something light as Pyramid/Pylons...CGI is so 90s and outdated....so WHY CGI?

Answer (score 5):

Here are 3 files [my.html, myCGI.py, myPyServer.py]. In windows XP I put them all in the same directory and double-click on myPyServer.py and things work very well.

my.html is the same as your html except:

```
yours: <a href="javascript:onTest('aaa.py', '')">Click it</a>
mine:  <a href="javascript:onTest('/myCGI.py', 'x=7')">Click it</a>
```

myCGI.py is pretty close to yours

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import os

input_data  = cgi.FieldStorage()
if input_data:
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    print "hello"
else:
    f = open('my.html', 'r'); s = f.read(); f.close()
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    print s
```

myPyServer.py

```
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import sys

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/"]         #make sure this is where you want it. [was "/cgi"]

PORT = 8000

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

# see effbot http://effbot.org/librarybook/thread.htm
def runserver():
    print "serving at port", PORT
    httpd.serve_forever()

import thread
thread.start_new_thread(runserver, ())

print "opening browser"

import webbrowser  
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myCGI.py'
webbrowser.open_new(url)

quit = 'n'
while not(quit=='quit'):
    quit = raw_input('\n ***Type "quit" and hit return to exit myPyServer.*** \n\n') 


print "myPyServer will now exit."

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can use plain old CGI if you want. Your code works fine for me. (The "abcdef" turns into "hello" when the link is clicked.)

You must have some simple error in your setup. I'd check file permissions on your test scripts (a+rx), which might have been overlooked. Also I assume you've got a "#!/usr/bin/env python" (or equivalent) at the top of your cgi script (it is omitted in your example above).

Answer (score 0):

Check out sajax:

http://www.modernmethod.com/sajax/

There's a python library and example in the download. You can have one CGI script that can handle your view and implement any AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple example using Python CGI and ajax.
http://www.ssiddique.info/writing-your-first-python-cgi-ajax-script.html